# Can we load Coloured images to a YML file?

Tags: python, yaml, facial-identification

How can I insert a RGB file into a .yml file to retrieve it for facial recognition? If I remove the grayscale conversion option then it gives this error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yash Raj\Desktop\sir ye wala folder hai\trainer PIL.py", line 25, in <module>
    recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:362: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Empty training data was given. You'll need more than one sample to learn a model. in function 'cv::face::LBPH::train  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

YAML by definition contains text using UTF-8 encoding, which is not suitable for storing arbitrary binary data.

Perhaps a suitable workaround is to store the file names of image files in the YAML data, and have your script or program load the actual data from that location.

If you really *have* to embed the images into your YAML file, you need to figure out a way to encode them. One common approach is to `base64` encode your binary data, though this tends to increase the storage requirements (`base64` encodes three input bytes into four ASCII bytes, so you get a 133% increase in size).

Somewhat esoterically, there are image formats which use  ASCII only; for example, [PNM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm).